# How to send child and get parent in the method?

Tags: c#, angular, oop, inheritance

I have in c#:

```
public class parent
{
    ...
}

public class child_1 : parent
{
    ...
}
public class child_2 : parent
{
    ...
}
```

I have to send an Angular son and I don't know which one,
the function in Angular:

```
func(p:parent):Observable<Array<parent>>
  {
    return this.http.post<Array<parent>>(this.url,p);
  }
```

and I can't get it in WebApi!
I try in c#:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Parent p)
        {
            ...
        }
```

and p come in parent's type,
and I can't convert him to the child.
I try to get it an object or dynamic but also I canwt convert him,
what can I do?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you have something like "Fruit" and special types of "Fruit" ("Apple" and "Orange"). On the client you send an "Orange" object and you want it to be deserialized as an "Orange" in C#, not as a "Fruit". Correct?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do here. What do you expect to receive at your endpoint?

Comment: If you have a relationship like father and son then inheritance is not the solution. If you are using inheritance with the right intention then you need to use custom model binder so that appropriate child class object created from the payload passed from angular.

Comment: I have something like "Fruit" and special types of "Fruit" ("Apple" and "Orange"). On the client you send an "Orange" object and you want it to be deserialized as an "Orange" in C#, not as a "Fruit"